# angular repeat item with parameters in html

Tags: angularjs

So I am trying to pull the variables from here.

```
<option ng-repeat="n in hp(20,25,30,40,50,75,100)">{{n}}</option>
```

or from inside the $scope

```
  $scope.featured = [
    {'hp': '20,25,30,40,50,75,100'}
  ];
```

my preference would be to use the scope to defined with scope and have it output to as I have more than one of these

```
<select>
    <option>{{content.hp}}</option>
</select>
```

however the problem is when I wrote the scope the way I have it I got errors is there a way to define more than one hp option for the dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, `hp` is a string but, you're really looking for an array.

Consider the following:

*model*

```
$scope.featured = {
  hp: [20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 75, 100]
};
```

*view*

```
<option ng-repeat="n in featured.hp">{{n}}</option>
```

However, it's probably best that you look into using [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

> The ngOptions attribute can be used to dynamically generate a list of  elements for the  element using the array or object obtained by evaluating the ngOptions comprehension expression.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-options` would helpful for your need. Just add `ng-model` with so that will add selected value to that `ng-model` variable inside scope.

```
<select ng-options="h in content.hp" ng-model="value"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ng-options` directive for the parent `<select>` element.
From the angular docs:

> The ngOptions attribute can be used to dynamically generate a list of  elements for the  element using the array or object obtained by evaluating the ngOptions comprehension expression

so if you define a data structure on your scope, you can use the `ng-options` directive to dynamically generate the options list for a select for you instead of ng-repeat. This also gives you greater control over the option value compared to the value eventually bound to your `ng-model` for the `<select>`.